# NullPointerException in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

I have a simple mvc spring application. I am getting the following error message from my Spring controller method when it attempts to pass control to a JSP.

Here is the relevant part of my controller.

```
@Controller
public class ReportsController {

@Autowired
private RecordsService recordsService;

@GetMapping("/reportEmployee")
public String listRecord(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("listRecord", recordsService.reportbyEmployee());
    return "report/reportEmployee";
}
```

}

```
@Service
public class RecordsServiceImpl implements RecordsService {

@Autowired
private RecordsDAO recordsDAO;

public List<Object[]> reportbyEmployee() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return recordsDAO.reportbyEmployee();
}
```

}

```
@Repository
public class RecordsDAOImpl implements RecordsDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public List<Object[]> reportbyEmployee() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    String hql="SELECT Records.employee.employee_id, SUM(case when Records.type=1 then 1 else 0 end),SUM(case when Records.type=0 then 1 else 0 end)" + 
            " FROM Records GROUP BY Records.employee.employee_id";
    List<Object[]> list = session.createQuery(hql).list();
    return list;
}
```

}

stack

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [springDispatcherServlet] in context with path [/Assignment] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionRegistry.findSQLFunction(SQLFunctionRegistry.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.findSQLFunction(SessionFactoryHelper.java:385)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode.getDataType(IdentNode.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:659)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.propertyRef(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1142)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.propertyRefLhs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5794)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.propertyRef(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1128)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2291)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectExprList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2232)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1503)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:585)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
```

Can anyone shed some light on this? Is the problem is due to @ Autowrite?

Comment: Are you calling /Assignment ?

Comment: Most probably it's because you are @Autowire a interface not, the implementation, therefore the interface doesn't know what implementation to use...

Comment: No. I'm sure it is an interface

Comment: Additionally you have, @GetMapping("/reportEmployee") but you are requestion /Assignment ..